# WPF: How to reset / recalculate ScrollViewer "ScrollableHeight"

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

**Background:**

I am generating the UI for a settings page.  The settings are stored within a Dictionary as the settings will be different for each *object* in question.

**Problem:**

The `ScrollableHeight` of a `ScrollViewer` is not acurate to the size of the content.  When the content of the `ScrollViewer` changes the **`ScrollableHeight` is not reset, but appends the height of the new content.**

**When:**

I am generating content within a `Grid`, which is a child element within the `ScrollViewer`.  The content being `RowDefinitions` where name-value pairs are displayed as `TextBlocks` and `TextBoxes`. When a different *object* is selected in order to edit its properties, the Grid's Children are cleared and the UI to display the properties is regenerated.  As I mentioned before in the problem defintion, the generated content's height is appended to the `ScrollViewer`'s `ScrollableHeight` property.

**What I have learned:**

My first thought was to clear the `ScrollViewer`'s `ScrollableHeight` and for each row added append the height of the row  in order to achieve the correct size.  The issue is that `ScrollableHeight` cannot be set (private setter).

**Code:**

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="svScroller"  Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid x:Name="gdPropertyGrid" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

C#:

```
//Get Selected Item
var listBox = ((ListBox)sender);
var provider = listBox.SelectedItem as IProviderConfiguration;

if (provider != null)
{
    tbTitle.Text = String.Format("Properties for {0}",provider.Name);

    int rowCount = 0;

    PropertyGrid.Children.Clear();

    //Get properties
    foreach (var property in provider.Properties)
    {
        //Create Grid Row
        var rowDef = new RowDefinition() {Height = new GridLength(30)};
        PropertyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);

        //Create Name Label
        var tbPropertyName = new TextBlock { 
                Text = property.Key,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center 
        };

        //Create Value input
        var tbPropertyValue = new TextBox {
                Text = property.Value.ToString(), 
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        };

        //Add TextBlock & TextBox Grid
        PropertyGrid.Children.Add(tbPropertyName);
        PropertyGrid.Children.Add(tbPropertyValue);

        //Set Grid.Row Attached property
        Grid.SetRow(tbPropertyName, rowCount);
        Grid.SetRow(tbPropertyValue, rowCount);

        Grid.SetColumn(tbPropertyValue, 1);

        rowCount++;
    }

 }
```

Comment: I would suggest using a ListBox and a DataTemplate to make this easier than using a ScrollViewer and Grid which you must perturb from code behind.

Comment: Agreed, a ListBox with a DataTemplate would allow for an elegant solution indeed. The above solution was taken with the goal in mind to develop the screen which would "match" the other screens which are TextBlock TextBox pairs within a Grid.  But you are correct this could be achieved with a DataTemplate.  I am not ever a fan of implementing UI in C# as it should be in XAML.

If the situation warrented it I would develop a complete PropertyGrid control or use an open source implementation as I saw fit such as http://www.codeplex.com/wpg.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior of [ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollableheight.aspx), from MSDN:

> Gets a value that represents the vertical size of the content element that can be scrolled.

Perhaps you are looking for [ScrollViewer.ViewPortHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportheight.aspx)? Or maybe you're looking for the ScrollViewer to stretch until a certain point before scrolling. In that case you'll need to look at another solution.

**EDIT**

The bug is you do not clear the RowDefinitions, hence the ScrollableHeight always appears to be appended to, since you constantly add new rows! My suggestion is you switch to using another ListBox and go with a Master-Detail pattern.

Comment: Meta-comment: the ScrollableHeight should equal Grid.ActualHeight. You can verify that with Snoop.

Comment: To clarify, the answer was "The bug is you do not clear the RowDefinitions". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sixlettervariables, from your description of the problem it sounds like you are trying to do something with the wrong property.  It's not clear to me precisely what your desired outcome is, I assume however that you want to be able to have different numbers of items in the same scroll viewer and have it expand as needed to display as many as possible at runtime.

ScrollViewer.ViewPortHeight lets you set the visible area and is a read/write property, and scrollbars will (by default) appear automatically when the content is too big to fit in the visible area.